# Hardware Compatibility Test (HCT) for windows 7

Tags: testing, windows-7

Is there HCT for windows 7 or do i need to install it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Control-Panel=>System in Windows-7. There, you will see your hardware compatibility information, and a rating provided by windows user-experience.

There will be a link called "Performance Information and Tools" where you can re-run these tests or find other information and tools for managing your hardware.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the test procedure given. It states there that "i.Start HCT Test Manager ii. Select Direct Sound Driver from Manual Test ... how can i start the HCT test manager?
"

Comment: To run performance assessment on windows machine: right-click on your computer and say "Properties". There will be a link called "Performance Information and Tools" on the lower left portion. Click that to view current scores for all hardware. To rerun the assessment, click the link below that says "Re-run the assessment".